Selenium is oppening an additional page with data:,
When I run the program, Selenium is opening the page I'm asking along with an additional tab with data:,
I'm using IntelliJ with Maven an this is my code:
package Selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
    }
}

Those are the dependecies for selenium:
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.27.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-manager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-manager</artifactId>
            <version>4.27.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


I forgot to mention that I'm using the latest chromedriver.exe from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe"); - Just remove this line from your code and try to run it.

Still the same outcome. But the weird part is that if I do driver.close(), it will close my youtube page and will leave the data:, page open with the driver still open (checked in the processes)

Is this ALL the code or just a portion of it? Sounds like you have multiple calls to open a new browser.

sounds like what would happen if you attached two drivers (or an IDE and driver) to the same browser.  Btw, driver.close() will only close the current tab/window.  Some drivers would also quit if it's the last opened window/tab, but you shouldn't rely on that.  Just use driver.quit() which will automatically close all windows/tabs, shutdown the browser and the driver.
